# How to connect multiple users to livechat in RocketChat?

Tags: meteor, chat, livechat, rocket.chat

Its needed to implement communication between several logged-in users (from one side) and an agent (or agents from another side).
Livechat is working good for agent-to-user chat, but how to connect several users in one livechat.
Default channel or private group functionality is not good for it, they have no agent-department relations and other things that has livechat. Also it requires additional development of client part.

So, how to configure livechat with multiple users?

Comment: Hey @alexloiko did you get any solutions for your problem? if you find please comment because i am also finding solutions for this problem

Comment: Hi, @sureshpareek. No, we did not found direct solution, just what I wrote before. Because of this we freeze our integration with Rocket.Chat.